# HTML-CSS: Strange fade in at load

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade, fullpage.js

I have a live [preview here](http://lucasdebelder.be/test/index.html) on my hosting. This demo is actually just a full page slider but when I add these lines of code, which makes it turn into a more like fade page 'slider'. I get all the other text quickly faded out on load which is annoying any work around?

```
 .fullpage-wrapper {
    width: 100%!important;
    transform: none!important;
}

    .fp-section {
        width: 100%!important;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
    }

    .fp-section.active {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the code?

Comment: Required: [mcve][

Comment: Consider using the [Fading Effect extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fadingEffect.html), which will give you more control and provide full compatibility with other options and features.

Comment: @Alvaro Yes I could but I don't have the cash to afford it. Anyways you have some great fullpage effects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to give the transition to the content too.

So if you just have an h1.

Something like this:

```
.fp-section h1 {
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.fp-section.active h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```